# Is this the right way to say it? à condition que/de

Tags: grammaire

Vous irez visiter ces îles exotiques à condition …

1. d'avoir
2. que vous ayez

… votre visa.

I'm pretty sure the 1st one is correct, but is the second one grammatically correct or not?

Answer (score 4):

Les deux formulations sont correctes.

1. Vous irez visiter ces îles exotiques à [condition d'avoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_condition_de) votre visa.
2. Vous irez visiter ces îles exotiques à [condition que](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_condition_que) vous ayez votre visa.

Comment: While the second sentence is grammatically correct, it is not idiomatic at all. I would agree with a teacher of French who marked it as wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, both are correct because the subject of the main sentence is the same as the subject of the subordinate condition (which is required to be able to use *"de"*). When the subjects are different, you have to use *"que"*:

2. Vous irez visiter ces îles exotiques à condition que l'ambassade vous délivre un visa.

Comment: I disagree. Using a conjugated verb here is not idiomatic 20th/early-21st century French, at least not in France.

Answer (score 1):

While the second form is grammatically correct and *à condition que + le/la/les* is common, *à condition d'avoir* "sounds better" and is in my opinion what most native speaker would chose.

Your question only appears in a [2012 Polish academic MCQ](https://www.oke.gda.pl/plikiOKE/Egzamin_maturalny/Arkusze_Egzaminacyjne/2012_wiosna/MJF-R1-1P-122.pdf) where you have to chose the "right" answer therefore I have absolutely no doubt about the fact *à condition d'avoir un visa* is the expected answer.

This is confirmed by [this page](https://gloswielkopolski.pl/matura-2012-jezyk-francuski-odpowiedzi-arkusze/ar/579839) which list it as correct.

[image]

To summarize, if you are a student learning French and using these tests as training material, I would recommend to memorize that ***à la condition d'avoir*** is the expected answer.

On the other hand, if you are a student who chose the ***à condition que vous ayez*** answer but a teacher counted you wrong, you can definitely challenge the decision since that form is not incorrect.

Note also that the indicative is also technically possible (see for example the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/condition)) leading to:

> *Vous irez visiter ces îles exotiques **à condition que vous avez** votre visa.*

> *Oui Monsieur, j'y consens bien volontiers, à la condition que vous **viendrez** dîner chez moi demain.* Maupassant, *Notre cœur*, 1890.

but nowadays, it would be hard to find someone not startled by it. The OQLF even [rejects the indicative](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4238).

Comment: I'm a native speaker. Do keep in mind that Goole Books searches books, but people do not speak like books, so this diagram doesn't necessarily reflect how people actually speak casually. I agree that when the subject is the same as in the original exemple, "de" feels lighter and more proper. However if I were to guess, I would say that when speaking casually, the use of "que" is more frequent.

Comment: @Jiliagre, that is a guess I made based on what I feel sounds more natural and less contrived in everyday French. "L'année prochaine, j'irai aux US à condition qu'j'aie mon visa." sounds more natural and casual to me than "L'année prochaine, j'irai aux US à condition d'avoir mon visa." which sounds more formal. In any case both are perfectly valid, could be said by a French native, and if there's a difference, it's rather subtle.

Comment: @Jonathan Due to popular demand, I have removed the controversial NGram and reworked my answer.

Answer (score 1):

“… *à condition d'avoir* …” is correct. The second sentence is grammatically correct, but not idiomatic at all.

When a verb can be constructed with either “*de* … [noun phrase]” or “*que* … [verb phrase]”, if the subject of the verb phrase is the same as the subject of the main clause, you must replace the verb phrase by *de* followed by an infinitive.

Not using the infinitive in this sentence feels to me (native speaker from France) as extremely outdated. It's something you might read in a 19th century (maybe even 18th century) book, but not something I would say. It may have survived in some local usage, but I don't remember encountering this often. If I heard it, I'd assume that the speaker lost his/her train of thought and forgot exactly how the sentence started.

I'm very surprised to see a native speaker suggest otherwise.